# How to observe the value in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to make my first Ember application and I am struggling with Ember.set() error.

My nextMonth function is working fine and rendering fine but if I add `{{month}}`
to my view I get an error.

View:

```
<h2>{{month}}</h2>
<button {{action "nextMonth"}}>Next</button>
{{#increment-for times=days }}

{{/increment-for}}
```

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

month: new Date().getMonth() + 1,
year: new Date().getFullYear(),

getDays: function(year, month){
  const date = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  this.set('days', date);
},

init: function() {
 this.getDays(this.month, this.year);
},

actions:{
  nextMonth: function(){
    if(this.month !== 12){
      this.set('month', this.month++);
    }
    else if(this.month === 12){
      this.set('month', 1);
      this.set('year', this.year++);
    }
    this.getDays(this.year, this.month);
 }
}
});
```

Comment: fyi, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and the Ember addon [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment) are nice tools for working with time and dates in JavaScript.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was incrementing with using ++. After changing it to this.month + 1 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `get` [method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_get) to get property value and `set` [method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_set) to set property value  only then ember features like ComputedProperty and Observer will be triggered and template value will be changed upon modification.

Like suggested in comments, go with addon [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment) you can install it using `ember install ember-moment` command. You will get lots of helpers to use it template and its wrapper for [moment.js popular library](https://momentjs.com/) so you can use all the methods available in this library in your js code just by doing `import moment from 'moment';`

Regarding your code, you can initialize `month` `year` in `init` method itself. dont for get to call super using `this._super(...arguments)` when you are using `Ember.Object`.